# How To Connect TFS to a Different Active Directory?

Tags: tfs, active-directory

Our IT department upgrades Active Directory to version 2016.

I am requested to test our TFS 2017 compatibility with Active Directory 2016. This is what the email says:

We invite you to test your application compatibility with Active Directory 2016, by connecting your application to our AD 2016 lab domain, and validating your application operates as expected.

LAB Domain Name: XXXX.XX.XXXX.NET

===========================================================
Domain Controller & Port Details:

YYYYY1.YYYYY.YY.YYY.NET
YYYYY2.YYYYY.YY.YYY.NET

Port: xxx/xxx

Base DN: DC=ZZ,DC=ZZZ,DC=ZZZZ,DC=ZZZZZ

## Users Scope: CN=Users,DC=ZZ,DC=ZZZ,DC=ZZZZ,DC=ZZZZZ

I have no idea where to begin and struggle to find any guides on connecting the existing TFS installation to a different Active Directory Domain.

I have a test installation of TFS which I am free to use without any impact on development etc.

Any advice welcome.

Comment: See the docs to move between domains: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883(v=vs.100).aspx#MoveAccounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention if there is a two-way trust between the two domains? If it is, users from your existing domain can pretty much be able to connect to the new TFS just by specifying the domain and users when authenticating.

This following documentation gives a good detailed account on working across domains

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-across-domains

Comment: @Evgeny And this article for your reference : [Trusts and Forests Considerations for Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253081.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that what I had to do was to join the computer with TFS installed to a new domain. And then do my testing.

I found out that it is a good idea to create a temporary local user on the PC and make it an administrator and remote desktop user. And then give it administrative rights in important applications: SQL Server, TFS Admin console etc.

What happened to me, for example, was that after I moved the PC to the new domain, I figured out that I cannot login into SQL Server anymore because the administrator account belonged to the old domain. The best solution I could think of was to move the PC back, create a temporary local user and make it SQL Server sysadmin. Then, after moving to the new domain again, make a real user from the new domain an admin, and remove the temporary local account.